# ASP.Net MVC: Why my inline html helper not printing anything

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to build UI with **ul/li** with my inline html helper but when i am running my program then it is not printing anything.

### see my code

```
@helper ShowTree(List<Scaffolding.Controllers.MenuItem> menusList)
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in menusList)
        {
            <li>
                <span>@item.Name</span>
                @if (item.Children.Any())
                {
                    @ShowTree(item.Children)
                }
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}

@{
    var menuList = ViewBag.menusList as List<Scaffolding.Controllers.MenuItem>;
    ShowTree(menuList);
}
```

### server side action code

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    List<MenuItem> allMenu = new List<MenuItem>
    {
    new MenuItem {Id=1,Name="Parent 1", ParentId=0},
    new MenuItem {Id=2,Name="child 1", ParentId=1},
    new MenuItem {Id=3,Name="child 2", ParentId=1},
    new MenuItem {Id=4,Name="child 3", ParentId=1},
    new MenuItem {Id=5,Name="Parent 2", ParentId=0},
    new MenuItem {Id=6,Name="child 4", ParentId=4}
    };

    List<MenuItem> mi = allMenu
    .Where(e => e.ParentId == 0) /* grab only the root parent nodes */
    .Select(e => new MenuItem
    {
    Id = e.Id,
    Name = e.Name,
    ParentId = e.ParentId,
    Children = allMenu.Where(x => x.ParentId == e.Id).ToList()
    }).ToList();

    ViewBag.menusList = mi;

    return View();
}
```

### POCO class

```
public class MenuItem 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<MenuItem> Children { get; set; }
}
```

what is wrong in my razor view code for which nothing gets printed. please give me some hint to find out the error. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try this correction:

```
@{
    var menuList = ViewBag.menusList as List<Scaffolding.Controllers.MenuItem>;
    @ShowTree(menuList);
}
```

if you want the code to output on page html you need to include a @ in prefix of your code syntax i.e. `@row.id` or `@mystring` or `@Html.Raw("<p>hello</p>")`